# How to save files/documents in another server in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web.config-transform

I have two servers.

My .NET Application is hosted in one server, now there is no space for save files in that server. Now i want to save files in another server. Is it possible.

I am saving files by using `Web.Config` file.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Filepath" value="C:\\Client Documents\\ Documents\\client"/>
  </appSettings>
```

If my new server IP Address is: `xx.xx.xx.x` then how can i change file path.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ServerFilePath` to `MyServer\SomePath`:

```
<add key="ServerFilePath" value="\\\\MyServer\\SomePath\\" />
```